# how to send data to google classroom

Tags: java, api, google-classroom

I have synced students and classes in my own application. So if I delete a student from my application then that student should also be deleted from google classroom.
Is it possible to do so. if possible can you please explain how it can be done.

Thanks

Comment: This is a place for specific programming questions (you did not post any code). Please attempt your project, and if you run into any specific issues come back with the code and ask a question then (after doing some research).

Comment: Hi, I don't need a complete code for this. I'm just asking that can i delete a user(student) from my application and that user(student) gets deleted from google classroom without providing the google credentials.
I tried "https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/{courseId}/students/{userId}" to work with this api call as well but i required google credetials when hit.

https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/delete?apix_params=%7B%22courseId%22%3A%22548166036816%22%2C%22userId%22%3A%22108375344947192179576%22%7D